# geth full node is too slwo.Only about 50 blocks can be synchronized per minute

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, cpp-ethereum

geth full node is too slwo.Only about 50 blocks can be synchronized per minute

However I use snap mode to sync very quickly.

Unfortunately what I need receipts for all transactions.

this is my server:

- CPU 16
- Memory 30G
- SSD 10T
- Bandwidth 10G
- net.peerCount 300

this is my geth command:

```sh
./geth --syncmode full --gcmode archive --maxpeers 500 --cache 2000 
./prysm.sh beacon-chain --accept-terms-of-use=true
```

What should I do to increase the sync speed? It's been a week and only 5 million blocks have been synced. At this rate, it will never be finished.